# Flutter Firebase: Current user gets data from sub-collection

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How does a current user accesses only his data in a subcollection?

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> myRide =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('Requests').snapshots();

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: myRide,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(snapshot.data['Name']),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
```

I also tried this:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> myRide = FirebaseFirestore
          .instance
          .collection('ADS')
          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
          .collection('Requests')
          .snapshots();
      
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: StreamBuilder(
              stream: myRide,
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data as Map<String, dynamic>; return Center(
                  child: Text(data['Driver Name']),
                );
              }),
        );
      }
```

But nothing. What I need to do. How can a user access his/her subcollection?

This is for the ListView.Builder option and this gives me blank screen.
The second option gives me an error as shown in the red screen

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> myRide = FirebaseFirestore
      .instance
      .collection('ADS')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .collection('Requests')
      .snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: myRide,
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            final data = snapshot.data!;
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      onTap: () {},
                      title: Text(data.docs[index].get('Name')),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          }),
    );
  }
```

[image: Result of second option]

[image: Result of third option]

And stackoverflow keeps telling me my post is mostly code. So I have to add this comment too.

Comment: Have you done authentication in your app?

Comment: yes. do I need the uid? and where?

Comment: Who can help please?

Comment: Will there be only one 'Request' here? Your second option looks like it should get the correct list of Snapshots, but I wonder if you may need to put those in some kind of a list view builder to get each request. Do you get any kind of error with the current build? or does it just show nothing?

Comment: Charlie Page - Yes, only one request. The thing is that the current user didn't make the collection 'ADS'. He makes the sub-collection 'Requests' in the the existing collection 'ADS'. So with this I want the current user to get the data in the collection 'ADS' that he(the current user) has made the request to. It's like you sending a friend request to a user and u want to know which user u have made the request to.

Comment: I've just edited the post. so please look at it

Comment: Any help please? I really stuck

Comment: Take a look at this [**`snippet`**](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#kdh8qla0zopnbhvf515t0f), If worked let me know so I will post as an answer. and if not worked then comment the problem you faced.

Comment: It still doesn't work. The screen is still blank

Comment: @EbenOasis any error or warning appeared if so share it ?

Comment: @Rohit Kharche - no warning, nothing. The page is just blank

Comment: I have tested that code in my env with top level collection as ADS which have sub-collection Requests and it is showing data for me. Can you also share snapshot of your DB ?

Comment: This is probably because The user who created the ADS main collection is the same user who created the Request sub-collection. In my case they are two different users. User A creates the ADS main collection and user B creates the Request subcollection

Comment: @EbenOasis Then you have to use User B's uid to access it by storing User B's uid in main ADS collection's document so you can retrieve it later OR use [collectionGroup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to access it.

Comment: Thank you very much but I've already found a way. I stored user B's Uid in the request subcollection and used the collectionGroup. After that I used a condition that if the Uid == currentUserId it should return the value and it worked.

Comment: If that worked can you post as an answer so other community members will also get the answer for this question. Otherwise let me answer it ?

Comment: How do I post it? Comments does not allow posting of codes. I think u can answer it anyway

Comment: Hi I have posted the answer take a look .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making it complex for getting documents from subcollections where the owner is user B, You can just store the User B’s uid in the nested subcollection Request so then you can query it using
[**`collectionGroup`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to query it with user B’s uid as it is already stored at the time of creating that document.

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> myRide =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('Requests').where('uid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).snapshots();
```

After fetching documents through the above query, you can then apply a filter for User A’s uid and compare it with current user uid, which could technically mean that User B’s ride has been fetched by User A(Rider).